# How do I label magick-montage images without their extension?

Tags: imagemagick

I can `montage` a few images (for demonstration here `convert`ed from text), but the label option includes the full filenames—with their extension.

```
target:
    for number in {1..6}; do \
        convert -gravity center -background SkyBlue -size 96x96 label:$$number -pointsize 24 $$number.png; \
    done
    montage -density 225 -label '%f' *.png -tile 3x -shadow -geometry '+8+8>'  all.jpg
```

How do I label magick-montage images without their extension?

[image: montage of images along with their filenames]

(In other words, I'd like the label under the image for `1` to be `1`, not `1.png`.)

Comment: Replace '%f' with '%t'.  See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for the answer and the pointer. This is so much better than the (very much web 0.1) page I'm used to seeing, as well as the always-incomplete man pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagemagick, %f means the full image.suffix, but %t is just the image (name) without the suffix.  So replace %f with %t in your montage command.  See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php for all the % string formats.